# PhoneGap Build: How not to offer app as an iPad version?

Tags: cordova, ipad, app-store-connect, phonegap-build

I have an app that I coded in phoneGap and built with phoneGap build. When I upload it to iTunes it wants me to publish screenshots for the iPad version, but I do not want to offer an iPad version.

Is this something I would change in my config.xml?

Comment: I believe ipads can use iphone apps, so I believe you should be able to ignore it (haven't personally tested this yet though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't** want to have tablet version use :

`<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />`

in your **config.xml** . More info [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/#target-device)

Comment: I did that but apparently apple will not allow you to change it once published as iPad compatible....